# css :active + draggable does not reset

Tags: css

I have the following css code:

```css
span:active {
    background: gold;   
}
```

```html
<span>span</span><br>
<span draggable="true">draggable span</span>
```

Just clicking on both spans, the color changes and resets afterwards.
However, after dragging the one span, it does not reset and is kept `:active`.

I'm using firefox 102. Is this a bug?
Are there css workarounds?

Comment: I don't know as yet which browser has a bug (if either of them do) but I can replicate the situation you describe on Firefox but not on Edge (both on Windows10). Using Edge the color disappears as soon as I complete the drag.

Comment: I've done some experiments with sensing dragend on FF and it seems that although the event is fired (ie FF realises the drag has finished) it does not then realise that the user has released the mouse - the span remains active. Can't think of any way around this using CSS without a bit of JavaScript.